# Probability of X or Y

Tags: probability

I've been trying to improve my knowledge on probability and can't seem to find any material that helps me out..

My question is..

*A survey was conducted that found 72% of respondents liked the new motorway. Of all respondents, 65% intend to drive more. Suppose that 81% of those who like the new motorway intend to drive more.*

First of all, is my tree diagram correct?

[image]

The questions are as followed.

a) Probability that a student likes the new motorway and intends to drive more.

- $0.81 * 0.72 = 0.5832 = 58.32$%

b) Probability that the student likes the new motorway or intends to drive more.

- This is what I'm trying to understand. From the formula, $P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B))$ how do I apply my answer? Is it .. $0.72 + 0.65 / 0.5832$?

c) Probability that the student neither likes the new motorway nor intends to drive more.

- Likewise with this one.

d) Probability that they don't like the new motorway given that they don't intend to drive more.

- $0.35 * 0.28 = 0.098 = 0.98$% ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The labels on the bottom branches are wrong, There is no reason to think they are $0.65$, $0.35$. The $0,65$ refers to all respondents, not new motorway haters. By the way, $0,5832$ is about $58\%$, not $5.8\%$.

Comment: Yeah oops, slight typo there. Mhmm in that case, are there any hints to solving that bottom branch?

Comment: Not yet, soon. First of all, for the second quesition you need to **subtract** the $0.5832$ from the sum $\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tree diagram is not correct. Namely the ends of the bottom branches should not read $0.65$ and $0.35$. The problem indicates that $65\%$ of ***all*** respondents intend to drive more, which includes those who like the new motorway. Your tree diagram indicates that $65\%$ of those who don't like the new motorway intend to drive more.

We know that $0.72\cdot0.81=0.5832$ is the portion of all respondents who like the new motorway and intend to drive more. The rest of the people who intend to drive more are people who do *not* like the new motorway, meaning that $0.65-0.5832=0.0668$ is the portion of people who do not like the new motorway and who intend to drive more. Dividing this number by $0.28$ will yield the number you should have on your tree diagram instead of $0.65.$ (Sadly, it isn't a nice decimal.)

Part (a) looks fine, now.

---

**Hints**: For part (b), what is the probability that a respondent likes the new motorway? What is the probability that a respondent intends to drive more? What is the probability that the respondent likes the new motorway and intends to drive more? What can you conclude, then, using your formula?

An alternate way of phrasing the question from part (c) is: "What is the probability that a respondent does not like the new motorway and does not intend to drive more?" This is directly related to the answer from part (b). It does not use the formula from part (b), though, and if you want to directly calculate it, then you're better off using an approach like you used in part (a).

For part (d), we have by definition that $$P(L'\mid D')=\frac{P(L'\cap D')}{P(D')}.$$ The numerator here is simply the answer to part (c), but what about the denominator? Well, what is the probability that a respondent doesn't intend to drive more and still likes the new motorway? What should you do with this number and the answer to part (c) to find the denominator?

Answer (score 1):

You did the first level right. You also did the top half of the second level right but not the bottom half of the second level. The reason is it states "of *all respondents*, $65\%$ intended to drive more"... not just the respondents who disliked the new motorway (which is what you did). Let's denote $P(D) = 0.65$ as the fraction of respondent who want to drive more. Let $P(L) = 0.72$, $P(L') = 0.28$ and $P(R) = 1$ denote the fraction of respondent who like the new motorway, don't like the new motorway and the last one is people who responded. So we have $$
0.65 = P(D) = P(D \cap L) + P(D \cap L') = P(L)P(D|L) + P(L')P(D|L') \\= (0.72)(0.81) + (0.28)P(D|L') \\ \implies P(D|L') = \frac{0.65 - (0.72)(0.81)}{0.28}
$$
The results, $P(D|L')$ is the values for $d$ in the bottom half since it is the fraction of people who want to drive out of the people who don't like the motorway.

Each equality is actually very intuitive if we use $N$ as the number of people. Then $N(D) = N(D \cap L) + N(D \cap L')$ since every one in $D$ must also be in either $L$ or $L'$. Now just divide both sides by $N(R)$ to get the second equality above. The third equality is from the fact that $P(D|L) = \frac{P(D \cap L)}{P(L)}$ which makes sense since $P(D|L)$ is the "fraction of people who drives, out of the people who already said they like the motorway".

Answer (score 0):

Two comments on notation:1) l is not the same as L, so L' is not the negation of l. 2) your diagram had d reused, which is either wrong (if you think they are part of the same population) or confusing.  For your question, no, because you applied the $65\%$ to those who don't like the motorway but it was over the whole population.  If you draw a Venn diagram your upper $d, d'$ will give the correct numbers.